# Regex on replaceAll()

Tags: java, regex

I want to transform this string

```
M,L,XL,XXL
```

to

```
size M,size L,size XL,size XXL
```

using *replaceAll()* method. Is it possible?

Comment: You want to use only `replaceAll()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using a Positive Lookahead.

```
String s  = "M,L,XL,XXL";
s = s.replaceAll("(?=(\\w+))\\b", "size ");
System.out.println(s); // size M,size L,size XL,size XXL
```

See [`Live demo`](http://ideone.com/Oiq3oN)

Regular expression:

```
(?=            look ahead to see if there is:
 (             group and capture to \1:
  \w+          word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or more times)
 )             end of \1
)              end of look-ahead
\b             the boundary between a word char (\w) and not a word char
```

Comment: Nice answer +1 used regex

Comment: @JqueryLearner note that the other answer also uses regexes, the fact that doesn't use complex wildcards and other regex patterns does not mean is not a regex at all.

Answer (score 3):

Play tricky on comma, and be **faster**:

```
"M,L,XL,XXL".replaceAll("M", "size M").replaceAll(",",",size ")
```

Comment: @JqueryLearner but this is a faster and simpler solution.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza yes I agree +1 from my side but this is not exactly as per OP

Comment: @codeMan [OP : original poster](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=op)

Comment: @JqueryLearner sometimes you want to use a flamethrower when you only need some matches...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I agree this is simpler but you also said this is faster.Is using regex makes performance slow?

Comment: @JqueryLearner of course it does. This is the first result I got when searching regex performance: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/01/regex-performance.html

Answer (score 2):

I would propose the following:

```
"M,L,XL,XXL".replaceAll("((?:\\w+)(?:,|$))","size $1")
```

as shown in http://fiddle.re/zrq88. The `$1` is a "backreference", referring to the first "capture group". A capture group is any text matched by an expression in parentheses, with some exceptions (e.g. when the left parenthesis is followed by `?:`).

See http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html for more information.